# Error “Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, ip, mysql-workbench, whitelist

I have used IP-Address, google script still gives "failed to establish a connection, invalid connection string, username or password", I have cross-checked data, and mysql port..everything is ok.. but still problem remains. HELP

Comment: Please consider providing the relevant parts of the code you're working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187573928) appears to be adding `?useSSL=false` to the URL:

```
var dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + IP + ":3306/" + DBNAME + "?useSSL=false";
```

It is working for me that way now. I am not using Google cloud mysql but another third party mysql.

Answer (score 0):

#### This appears to be a bug.

This was reported several times in Issue Tracker during the last few days:

- [AppScripts get a "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187573928)

This was already reported internally by Google and any updates about this will be communicated there. Please consider [subscribing to this issue by starring it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing it.